# keys() operation in python Explanation?

Tags: python

I dont understand how exactly the last line of this code is needed, can someone kindly please explain it? thanks in advance!

```
ops = {'+': operator.add,'-': operator.sub,'*': operator.mul} #creating a dictioanry, using 'operators' built in functions

keys = list(ops.keys()) # ['+', '*', '-'] list The method keys() returns a list of all the available keys in the dictionary.
opt = random.choice(keys)  #e.g. '+'  randomly choose an operator/key/ from the dictionary
operation = ops[opt]
```

Comment: operation = ops[opt] selects the value of key opt in ops, for example if opt = '+' then operation is operator.add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ops is a dictionary
- opt is a random key

if opt = "+",  then  ops[opt] =  operator.add

you should look at the dictionary of python.

Comment: so the code 'ops' is a part of the operator module in python?

Comment: In your code   ops is a dictionary ,    a set of operator

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you don't need the last line.  You can just use "ops[opt]" wherever it is that you might consider using "operation".